An analog of Anderson's result in C* algebra setting
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a unital $C^{*}$-algebra and $S(\mathcal{A})$ denote the states space of $\mathcal{A}$.
For $a\in \mathcal{A}$ , define $W(a) =\{\phi(a):\phi\in S(\mathcal{A})\}$
It's known that $W(a)$  is a non-empty convex compact set in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $I$ is an essential ideal of $\mathcal{A}$.
Conjecture: If $a\in I$ and $W(a) \subset \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and $W(a) \cap \mathbb{T}$ is infinite, then $W(a) =\overline{\mathbb{D}}$
Redefine $W(a) =\{\phi(a):\phi\in \mathcal{A}^{*} : \phi(1)=1=\|\phi\|\}$

I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a moving target. I recommend taking some time to formulate a definite question and test it on some obvious examples before posting.

For instance, in Edit 2, isn't the set of such phi just the set of states? In which case, your "redefinition" of W(a) is just the same as the original definition.

Note that my example can be adapted to show $W(a)$, as originally defined, can be any compact convex set, so your edit 1 or any similar edit is completely hopeless. As for edit 2, as written, $W(a)$ is literally ${1}$, so I have no idea what you’re asking about.

@YemonChoi I concur. In fact, as written $W(a)$ is even worse, since it’s written as $\phi(a) = 1$ instead of $\phi(1) = 1$.

No, this is not true. For example, let $\mathcal{A} = \ell^\infty \oplus \ell^\infty$ and $I = \ell^\infty \oplus c_0$. Let $\{\alpha_n\}_n$ be a dense sequence in the right half of the closed unit disk in the complex plane (i.e., the closure of $\{\alpha_n\}_n$ is $\{x \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}: \text{Re}(x) \geq 0\}$). Let $a = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots) \oplus 0 \in I$. It is then not hard to check that $W(a)$ is $\{x \in \overline{\mathbb{D}}: \text{Re}(x) \geq 0\}$, contradicting your conjecture.
